# Why does this Python function return an UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python

Can anybody explain why this function is returning the following error?

The function:

```
def scatter_x_y(self,filtered_data,x_parameter,y_parameter):
    for i in range(len(filtered_data)):
        if filtered_data[i].name==x_parameter:
            x=filtered_data[i]
            x_index=list(x.keys())
        elif filtered_data[i].name==y_parameter:
            y=filtered_data[i]
            y_index=list(y.keys())
    print x_index
```

The error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x_index' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: As you iterate over all of `filtered_data` and only ever need `i` to index `filtered_data`, consider to use the `for` loop with its default 'foreach' semantics, i.e. *without* wrapping `filtered_data` in `range(len(...))`: `for d in filtered_data: if d.name==x_parameter: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the loop never executes, `x_index` is undefined.  Neither is `y_index`; its value is only ever seen briefly since it isn't defined outside of the `elif` it's seen in.

You might have intended to move the printing inside of the loop, as the values for `x_index` and `y_index` only exist for one iteration.  Otherwise, printing it or using the value would only net you the last calculated value(s).  You would then want to declare them *inside* of the loop, or we'd run into the same issue when we go to print it out.  This also prevents unnecessary repeated printing of either value when we don't really expect it to be printed out.

```
def scatter_x_y(self,filtered_data,x_parameter,y_parameter):
    for i in range(len(filtered_data)):
        x_index, y_index = None, None
        if filtered_data[i].name==x_parameter:
            x=filtered_data[i]
            x_index=list(x.keys())
        elif filtered_data[i].name==y_parameter:
            y=filtered_data[i]
            y_index=list(y.keys())
        if x_index:
            print "x_index={}".format(x_index)
        if y_index:
            print "y_index={}".format(y_index)
```

Comment: This will crash during the first run of the loop because either `x_index` or `y_index` (or both) will not be set.

Comment: Still not correct. If you initialize the values before the loop (e.g. `x_index = None`) it will be fine.

Comment: so, why the extra `if`s? Put the print after defining `x_index`.

Answer (score 1):

If the loop doesn't executes, `x_index` is never initialized.

I believe x_index is a vector, so try this:

```
x_index=[]
def scatter_x_y(self,filtered_data,x_parameter,y_parameter):
    for i in range(len(filtered_data)):
        if filtered_data[i].name==x_parameter:
            x=filtered_data[i]
            x_index=list(x.keys())
        elif filtered_data[i].name==y_parameter:
            y=filtered_data[i]
            y_index=list(y.keys())
    print x_index
```

Comment: `x_index` is still not assigned as local variable.